# 64bit Integer has the same limit as 32bit integer

Tags: java, int, max, long-integer

This is just a short question but I'm still curious. When I initialize a `int` variable with the highest value 2147483647 it's allright. but when I want to initialize a `long` and assign it to it's max value, it gives me a "number too large" error

```
int i = 2147483647;
long j = 9223372036854775807;
```

Comment: Show us your code!

Comment: Almost certainly you forgot to add the L at the end of the literal.  Check the dupe link.

Comment: @thatotherguy thx, forgot that detail with the "L" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`9223372036854775807` is an `int` literal, but is too large to fit into an `int`, hence the error. You can use a `long` literal instead by adding `L` to the end of it:

```
long j = 9223372036854775807L;
// Here --------------------^
```